# Relation between $\dim V^G$ and the number of orbits of a given linear representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

In the context of linear representations of finite groups, we know that
$$\dim V^G=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\text{tr } \rho(g)= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|V^g|,\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$
where $V^G$ is the vector subspace of $V$ given by
$$V^G:=\{v\in V\:|\:g\cdot v=v\text{ for all } g\in G\}$$
and $V^g$ is the set of fixed points by $g$.

By Burnside's lemma, it is clear that $\dim V^G$ is the number of orbits in our representation.

Could someone clarify this a bit? I don't see this as obvious. Is there any other way of seeing that besides using Burnside's lemma and equation $(1)$?

Comment: The number of orbits in a representation is usually infinite. I think you want to require $V$ to be a permutation module -- i.e., require that there is a basis $X$ of $V$ which is permuted by $G$ (this means that $gx \in X$ for each $g \in G$ and $x \in X$). Then $\dim V^G$ is the number of orbits of the $G$-set $X$.

Comment: I think you are mixing up $|V^g|$ with $\dim V^g$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That was exactly what I did. Thank you